# Prototype startsWith OR

Tags: javascript, prototype, startswith

I am trying to use Prototype and startsWith but I want to check a number of values and little confused how to do this.

Basically have this code:

> if(Category.startsWith("[Test1] " ||
>   "Test " || "Test2 ")) { some stuff }

It doesn't appear to be working and just wondering what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @Tom: (Re your comment on my answer.) Actually, spender didn't respond first, I did. (If he had, when I noticed I was second and that our answers were effectively identical, I would have removed my answer -- common courtesy.) But glad in any case your question has been answered.

Comment: hi T.J :) oh apologies i just looked at the time? really appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not a problem (although you can change it if you want). Not sure what you mean about the times, they show I responded first (although again, it's not like it's a big deal, though I *do* wish people would remove obviously duplicate answers.)

Comment: sure :) i have "answered 34 mins ago - spender" and "answered 35 mins ago - T.J. Crowder. so I just thought this meant spender answered - sorry new to all this ;P

Comment: Right, 35 minutes *ago* is earlier than 34 minutes *ago*. *Please* don't worry about it, it's not important. I only commented because you'd called out the times in your reply to my answer (and I'm kicking around SO procrastinating when I should be working). :-) Welcome to SO and have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do them individually:

```
if(Category.startsWith("[Test1] ")
   || Category.startsWith("Test ")
   || Category.startsWith("Test2 ")) {
    // some stuff
}
```

In JavaScript, the expression

```
"[Test1] " || "Test " || "Test 2 "
```

...evaluates to `"[Test1] "`, because `||` returns the first "truthy" operand.

Comment: super worked :) thanks a lot. spender responded first but thanks so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Category.startsWith("[Test1] ")
    ||Category.startsWith("Test ")
    ||Category.startsWith("Test2 ")) 
{ 
    //some stuff
}
```

Comment: oh great ok - ill give this a shot ))